# How to Configure database mail in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, email, configuration

I'm tried to configure the database mail with Gmail SMTP Server, getting a message like:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail
>   server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 4 (2019-01-11T14:46:42).
>   Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Failure sending
>   mail.).

Can anyone give solutions for this

Comment: Hi, I think this question is not enough specific to allow somebody to support... I mean... the E-Mail configuration has several steps, need to connect with the External server maybe through Proxy...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general, but the first step is to create a profile and account using `Configure Database Mail Wizard`: In `Object Explorer`, go to *Management* > *Database Mail* and *Create a new e-mail profile and specify its SMTP accounts*.

Once that's done you can test by sending an email, like this:

```
USE msdb
GO
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='ProfileName',
@recipients='test@Example.com',
@subject='Title email',
@body='This is the body of my email'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your port and server adress to your mail. For example:
Port: 587 
server: smtp.gmail.com
Remember, your SQL Agent should be enable.